# vue-utils Get value of model after be event of keydown

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Hello.
I have to write test of "when component have counter is 2, then the user can only type two chars":

```
 propsData.model = ''
    propsData.length = 2
    const wrapper = mountFunction({propsData})
    const input = wrapper.find('input')
    await input.trigger('keydown', {
        key: 'a'
      })
    await input.trigger('keydown', {
        key: 'a'
      })
    await Vue.nextTick()
    console.log(wrapper.findComponent({name: 'v-text-field'}))
    console.log(wrapper.vm.$refs.input.$refs.input)
```

But, when I check value, then length allways is 0.
I tried DOM Native Events, but doesn't work too. Any of ideas?

Answer (score 0):

input.trigger('keydown') - its event for @keydown.
Input element use @input event for updating value . Probably .trigger('input' , 'a') - that's what you need